# libxml-ruby on windows xp problem

Tags: windows-xp, failed-installation, libxml-ruby

About a month ago I installed libxml-ruby using 
gem install libxml-ruby
and it worked fine.
Then i went to install it on another machine today and it failed with this error:

```
C:\Windows\system32>gem install -r libxml-ruby
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing libxml-ruby:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/bin/rake RUBYARCHDIR=c:/ruby/lib/ruby/
gems/1.8/gems/libxml-ruby-1.1.3-x86-mswin32-60/lib RUBYLIBDIR=c:/ruby/lib/ruby/g
ems/1.8/gems/libxml-ruby-1.1.3-x86-mswin32-60/lib
'c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/bin/rake' is not recognized as an int
ernal or external command,
operable program or batch file.


Gem files will remain installed in c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/libxml-ruby-1.
1.3-x86-mswin32-60 for inspection.
Results logged to c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/libxml-ruby-1.1.3-x86-mswin32-6
0/ext/mingw/gem_make.out
```

I have rake installed and win32-api

I then got confused if I had really installed libxml-ruby on my machine previously and tried uninstalling and reinstalling it. It now fails with the same error message on my machine and some scripts i've written to parse xml, which used to work, no longer work. Has anyone else tried installing libxml-ruby lately on windows xp? It appears to be completely broken.

Comment: I ended up switching to using nokogiri. It seems to work just as fast and its got all the functionality from what I can tell (slightly nicer syntax as well).
Most importantly though, installation didnt have any problems on any computers I've tried so for (windows and linux machines)

Comment: Eventually the root problem was fixed and you can now install libxml-ruby (last time i tried anyways)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the same problem, and ended up figuring out a decent work-around.

It seems the error is correct

```
'c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/bin/rake'
```

isn't a valid executable.  It needs to run rake from the root ruby/bin folder, where the wrapping batch file can be found.

Rummaging through the rubygems code, I found that Gem::Ext::RakeBuilder tries to build extensions using

```
cmd = ENV['rake'] || Gem.bin_path('rake') rescue Gem.default_exec_format % 'rake'
```

So, simply setting the rake environment variable to something valid before running the gem install should help:

```
C:\>set rake=c:\ruby-1.8.6-26\bin\rake.bat

C:\>gem install libxml-ruby --no-rdoc --no-ri
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed libxml-ruby-1.1.3-x86-mswin32-60
1 gem installed
```

(I skipped installing rdoc and ri because it prints out a bunch of formatting warnings, making it more difficult to paste the results in here.)

Comment: Thank you for the tip with "set rake=..", Nick ! It works just fine.